# Why the UDP header has 'Length' field?

Tags: udp, network-protocols, rfc

What is the purpose of the 'Length' field in the UDP header? Given that there is also a 'Length' field in the IP header and the length of the UDP header is constant.

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the answers I found convinced me.

If it's for IP Fragmentation - as far as I understand this, IP fragmentation breaks the UDP datagram into multiple IP frames, and then the IP layer in the receiving host reassembles the frames, using the 'Length' field from the IP header, into a UDP datagram, without the UDP layer even knowing the datagram was fragmented.

If it's because we can't assume the protocol used by the network layer is IP - maybe I don't understand correctly the exact form in which the transport layer receives the data from the network layer, but isn't it true that the transport layer receives from the network layer only the UDP header & data? If it's true, then it doesn't matter which protocol is used by the network layer.
And if the transport layer receives the data in a form of stream of bits instead of block of data, then how can it calculate a checksum on the whole UDP headers & data?

I also can't accept the answer that this field is redundant, because I learned that in the times when the RFC was developed, every bit was important and there weren't bits without a dedicated purpose.

I hope you can help me get this matter clear.
Thank you!

Comment: Because IP packet lengths can be rounded up.

Comment: A bit rude answer UDP is UDP, you cannot bet on the fact it will be carried by IP. An UDP packet could even be the payload of a TCP packet in some weird scenarios. When a carrying protocol packet is received, and its payload de-encapsulated, the contained packet (for example UDP) must remain self consistent, so the length field is required.

Comment: @Cubo78, But the UDP header length is constant, right? So can't I know the protocol above TCP is UDP by the protocol field from the IP header, and then substract the UDP header length from the total length and get the UDP data length?

Comment: @user207421, Even if it's rounded up, it will be included in the length field of the IP header, so why does it matter?

Comment: UDP is designed to work over different network layers (as many other protocols). The UDP logic will keep tring to receive IP (or whatever) frames until the number of bytes received is equal to the length field in the UDP header. Only then the datagram will be delivered up to the next layer (on Windows machines this wait can take many minutes...). This layer doesn´t care (and doesn´t know) anything about the network layer (i. e. it doesn´t "know" the IP length, or its header length (which is variable btw)

Comment: @C.Gonzalez, What does it mean? How can UDP header be on a layer other than the transport layer and why? Do you have a reference for me for more reading? And about the answer, in 'will keep trying to receive IP frames", you mean in IP Fragmentation? But isn't the layer which did the fragmentation on one side will be the one to reassemble the fragments on the other side, so that the layer which handles the UDP header won't even know that fragmentation has occured?

Comment: If you want to dive deep into protocols, start with [TCP/IP illustrated from Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Illustrated). To me still the bible of protocols, although more modern stuff may be available. Ignoring layers for a second: UDP being self-contained (independent of the protocol used beneath it), the UDP logic will keep waiting for bytes to be delivered to it (by whatever layer is below), until length bytes are in. Since it cannot assume a specific MSS, it doesn´t know the size of the "chunks" (packets) it will get.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez, I looked at rfc 791 & 815, and it said "...At this point, the datagram has been completely reassembled and can be passed to higher protocol levels for further processing". As far as I understands this, the network (or any other) layer handles the reassembly of the frames, and only after all the frames have arrived it does the reassembly and then passes it to the next layer. This means the next layer receives the udp header and all of the udp data at once, it doesn't needs to wait for another data to arrive, so why does it needs the udp length? And thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found an answer -

In "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tsvwg-udp-options-01" it says that:

> "The UDP Length length field is typically redundant".

I think that if it's under the domain "ietf.org", I can trust that...

More details in the above link for those interested. (sections 4 & 9)

Thanks to the responders!